Randomly getting "ValueError: PyCapsule_New called with null pointer" when making plots with Python 3.12 fresh install on new PC
I use a suite of python 3.7 code for my work, generating various plots and fitting lines. It works perfectly fine on my old windows 10 machine.
However, I just got a new laptop and installed 3.12 on it. The code still works, but SOMETIMES it randomly decides to fail on a plot, giving "ValueError: PyCapsule_New called with null pointer" originating from a simple line of code that I use to initialize new plots: plt.figure(figsize=(figx,figy)) #generate clean figure.
I  can see no rhyme or reason as to why it sometimes works and occasionally fails. In a few instances, I've literally just changed the order of certain plots and it works just fine. In others, I change minor details like the initial guess for the center of a gaussian for a line fit (by one index), and it works just fine all of a sudden.
I'm at a loss as to how to move forward with this, as the problem seems to be some random, arcane issue buried deep within matplotlib or python or something, clearly relating to something with the fresh install on my new machine.
Any suggestions?
Full error below:
File "D:\astra\ASTRA MS\Massify.py", line 435, in <module>
    ASTRA_MS.plot_set(x_m,t,y_ms,y_blur,y_superblur,y_megablur,figtext,titletext,shotnum,plotstyle=plotstyle,savepath=path,falling=falling,vlines=vlines,vacc=vacc,xlim=xlim,showplots=showplots,invertplot=invertplot,metadata=str(values))
  File "D:\astra\ASTRA MS\ASTRA_MS.py", line 259, in plot_set
    plt.figure(figsize=(figx,figy)) #generate clean figure
  File "C:\Users\zachu\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 1022, in figure
    manager = new_figure_manager(
  File "C:\Users\zachu\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 545, in new_figure_manager
    return _get_backend_mod().new_figure_manager(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\zachu\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\matplotlib\backend_bases.py", line 3521, in new_figure_manager
    return cls.new_figure_manager_given_figure(num, fig)
  File "C:\Users\zachu\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\matplotlib\backend_bases.py", line 3526, in new_figure_manager_given_figure
    return cls.FigureCanvas.new_manager(figure, num)
  File "C:\Users\zachu\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\matplotlib\backend_bases.py", line 1811, in new_manager
    return cls.manager_class.create_with_canvas(cls, figure, num)
  File "C:\Users\zachu\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\_backend_tk.py", line 479, in create_with_canvas
    with _restore_foreground_window_at_end():
  File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\contextlib.py", line 137, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "C:\Users\zachu\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\_backend_tk.py", line 43, in _restore_foreground_window_at_end
    foreground = _c_internal_utils.Win32_GetForegroundWindow()
ValueError: PyCapsule_New called with null pointer


Looks like a bug in matplotlib, it's been addressed on the main branch: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/28269.
But not included in a release at the time of writing.
For the time being, could create a 3.7 env & see if the problem persists.

I also get this stacktrace intermittently in my Azure DevOps python test pipelines on Windows Microsoft-hosted agents. I've seen it in Python 3.9 and 3.12, but never on Linux. I'm using matplotlib 3.9.0 and the tkagg backend too, so the bug at https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/28267 sounds plausible!

I also get this error too .  I get it running the program from the command line, idle or vscode.  My code crashes after calling subplot. I am running the same python3.12 and this hasn't been a problem until recently.  I have added code to save away the data to be plotted in a json file.   I can then load that code and plot it in a much simpler program that ONLY plots the data by calling the same tempplot ( temperature plot ) routine.  This never crashes.    i

I encountered this issue with matplotlib 3.9.0. It's a known bug and the advice is to either wait for the next update or install matplotlib from the github repo. I did the latter and it resolved the issue.
For anyone pip installing from a requirements.txt file, simply replace matplotlib with matplotlib@git+https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib.git.

What are you using to run your code? IDLE? Anaconda? Something else?
Was using matplotlib and seaborn for plotting scatterplots within a loop, and it kept giving me the error “ValueError: PyCapsule_New called with null pointer”. Couldn’t figure out how to fix it, I was running the code in Python IDLE. SOMETIMES a few of the graphs would show properly and then randomly would stop working for the second or third graph and give me that error. When I switched to using Anaconda Jupyter Lab for running the code, this resolved the issue right away! Suddenly it was able to plot the graphs just fine.
If you’re using Python IDLE, would recommend switching to Anaconda. Download Anaconda, go to Anaconda Navigator, open Jupyter Lab, navigate to your folder where your data is located, open a new Jupyter notebook file, and copy paste your code to press the “play” (run) button there.

It's probably not necessarily the source or using with IDLE vs. another way, such as Jupyter. It's probably actually the versions as the OP and commenters indicate. Anaconda tries to include in their base installs combinations of Jupyter software and common packages, like Matplotlib, that play well together. It tends to be behind because it takes care to try and make sure the versions are fairly stable. The OP's problem and this issue and this issue are fairly new ...

 and probably using new software. Because the Anaconda's base install includes more established older combinations, it wouldn't probably have that issue. However, if you made a new conda environment and installed all new things and then activated that you might encounter this even with JupyterLab. So it's important to understand what is really contributing to the issues when troubleshooting.

Experiencing same issue and couldnt find a real fix so far. Since it is random with a rather low chance to occur I added a try statement, except the ValueError and loop until it works.
done = False
while not done:
    try:
        plt.figure(figsize=(figx,figy))
        done = True
    except ValueError:
        continue



I was facing same issue with matplotlib 3.9.0. I downgraded the matplotlib to 3.8.4 and issue is not repeated after that. If you are ok to downgrade, this is an option.
pip install --force-reinstall -v "matplotlib==3.8.4"

Note : If you are using numpy with pandas, you may have to re-install supported version.
